# Long texts with vertical scroll bar in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

On the web site I create I  need to have sections with long texts in small places. I would like to add a vertical scroll bar to the texts, so they will be scrollable. I use the  free version of Elementor. Is it possible to do it, or I will need to buy Elementor Pro? Is it easy to do with Elementor Pro? Is there a plugin to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In `dashboard > appearance > customize > Additional CSS` add "overflow-y:scroll;" to the div tag which you can find using your browser's developer tools.  This will force a vertical scrollbar on every instance of that div tag.

If you only want a scrollbar when it is needed because the text is too long, add "overflow-y:auto;"

Comment: I create a web site (pushkin.sapir.us). I am not sure, what my browser has to do with it? Everybody, who sees my web site, needs to see these texts with the scroll bars.

Comment: You use your browser dev-tools to find the tag of the div that you want to have the scroll bar e.g. <div class="elementor-widget-container"> then you add the new decaration (property:value) e.g. .elementor-widget-container{overflow-y:auto;}

Comment: What is the point of this? I create the website in WordPress with Elementor

Comment: You asked a question on how to solve a problem.  I have given you a solution.

Comment: If you don't understand how CSS works and how you can use it to do powerful things, then you are going to have to be satisfied with the way Elementor builds your site for you and give up that control.

Comment: I do not understand what my browser has to do with it. My web site has to work with any browser, forever.